# shadow for semitransparent meshes too dark

Tags: three.js

I've a box which is almost transparent (opacity is set to 0.1) but the shadows are very dark (see http://jsfiddle.net/dskb80jq/4/). Where is the "shadow calculation take opacity into account" switch?

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
```

Thats my Material and Mesh:

```
// Create material
material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
material.transparent = true;
material.opacity = 0.1;

// Create cube and add to scene.
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
```

Now there shall be light:

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1000.0);
spotLight.position.set(400, 400, 200);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 10;
spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 1500;  
scene.add(spotLight);
```

Now.. well I'd expect are very light shadow. Where is the missing part?

Comment: What you are looking for is currently  (`R98`) not possible since it's a limitation of  `three.js`'s shadow technique. Read the following github issue for more information: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10600

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Are you aware of a technique to simulate different shadow intensities?

Comment: You might want to give [ShadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial) a try. It is used in this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html). You can control the shadow intensity by modulating the `opacity` property.

Comment: That's it! Cheers mate. http://jsfiddle.net/dskb80jq/9/